# Angular - get data length without using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm working with angular, and i need to be able to display an array length but without using `ng-repeat`.

here's the scenario:

I have default.json:

```
{
 { ...
   "data":
      [{
        "name":"Test",
        "errors":
          [
           {"id": 1,"level": 2,"details": {...}},
           {"id": 3,"level": 1},
           {"id": 5,"level": 1},
           {"id": 5,"level": 1},
           ....
          ],
        },
        {
         "name":"Test",
         "errors":
          [
           {"id": 1,"level": 2,"details": {...}},
           {"id": 5,"level": 1},
           ....
          ],
        }
      ],
    ....
  }
}
```

then I've created myData from the controller, so that I can do something like `ng-repeat="data in myData"` and i can use it properly.

Now, here's the question:

I Need to have a recap of all the errors, a sum of all the errors in the objects.

I tried to do something like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="data in myData">
<i ng-repeat="error in data.errors">{{error.length}}</i>
</span>
```

and nothing was printed. So I tried:

```
<span ng-repeat="data in myData">
<i>{{data.errors.length}}</i>
</span>
```

and the result was:

> 4 2 0 0 0 0 0

and it makes sense, because my first object as 4 errors, my second one 2 and so on...

But what I'd like to see is only: **6**, as there are 6 errors in total.

How can I get only one value that sums all the errors from all the objects I've got without having to use `ng-repeat` (I think I don't need it there)

Hope this question is clear enough, thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not create a new scope variable and add your data.errors.length onto it? Just like scope.maxLength += data.errors.length ?

Comment: Yes. It make sense. I didn't though about that. I'll give it a go. Thanks for now

Comment: You may do that in your controller, using Angulars `forEach` function or whatever you desire.

Comment: `{{data.errors.reduce( (prev, curr) => prev + curr )}}`

Comment: @JoseRocha your solution doesnt work

Comment: @Nick `{{data.errors.length.reduce( (prev, curr) => prev + curr )}}` for a list `[4,2,3,1,0].reduce( (prev, curr) => prev + curr );` the result is '10' it should be working. and for [4,2,0,0,0,0,0].reduce( (prev, curr) => prev + curr ); the result is 6

Comment: @JoseRocha i get this error: Syntax Error: Token ',' is unexpected, expecting [)]

Comment: @Nick can you try `.reduce(function(prev,curr){ return prev + curr})`

Comment: @JoseRocha i get this error instead: Syntax Error: Token '{' is unexpected, expecting [)]

Comment: @Nick Ok i know what is the problem so make this on the markup put `{{sum(data.errors.length)}}` and on the controller make a function for the scope `$scope.sum = function(array) {
                return array.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr);
            }`

Comment: as the solution is pure JS I would actually say there could be javascript tag and at most one angularjs

Comment: @ciekawy added javascript tag

Comment: @JoseRocha i get another type of error: array.reduce is not a function

Comment: @Nick can you show me the array value that reaches the sum function?

Comment: @JoseRocha here's what happens on the console: 4 - error - 2 - error - 0 -error - 0 - error ... and so on...it is not an array but it is printed as int and iterate (with error i mean the one i write above)

Comment: having some simple plunkr would help providing an answer directly related to your case

Comment: @Nick `return $scope.myData.data.map(function(o){ return o.errors.length}).reduce((prev,curr) => {return prev +curr})` inside the sum function

Comment: @JoseRocha from the provided example it's clear that `$scope.myData` is an array at the moment of the evaluation

Comment: otherwise having no exact working example this is just guessing while the solution is pretty clear and its just a matter of integration with existing code...

Comment: @Nick check the plunker on my answer below and tell me if it is that what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), so you can use the reduce like this

```
var result = array.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr);
```

if the array is `[4,2,0]` the `result` it will be `6`

so a possible solution will be on the markup call a function in scope

```
{{arraySum(data.errors.length)}}
```

and the function will be

```
$scope.arraySum= function(array) {
    return array.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr);
}
```

**EDIT**
for this edit we will use the function [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

markup

```
{{totalErrors()}}
```

code

```
$scope.totalErrors = function(){
    if ($scope.myData)
        return $scope.myData.data.map(function(o){ return o.errors.length})
                                 .reduce((prev,curr) => {return prev + curr})
}
```

I have created a plunker from what i understand that is your data you can see it working **[here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7BGqsIzKVVFHyw3l0nPn?p=preview)**

[**Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0UtQkZFAqJob66LK6OKz?p=preview) is a plunker that simulates the delay of an ajax request using $timeout. It uses [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) on markup to prevent displaying raw data.

Answer (score 1):

You should do in this way in your controller

```
 var sum=0;
 for(var i=0;i<$scope.MyData.length;i++)
 {
   var error=[];
   error=$scope.MyData[i].errors;
   sum=sum+error.length;

 }
 alert(sum+'');
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code in the controller (updated for the promise)

```
function countErrors(myData) {
  $scope.totalErrors = myData
    .map(function(data) { 
      return data.errors.length; })
    .reduce(function(acc, errorsLenght){
      return acc += errorsLenght }, 0)
}
$scope.myData.$promise.then(countErrors)
```

Comment: i get this error: $scope.myData.map is not a function

Comment: the only thing coming into my mind is that you're loading myData using `$http` or `$resource` - I've updated the response for such case

Comment: yes i'm using $http to load my data. I'm going to try your solution and if it doesnt work i'll create a plunkr